# what is divergence of $\text{div} (nu)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $n$ be the density of the fluid and $u\in \mathbb R^3$ its velocity field.

My Question is: what is $\text{div} (nu)$?

Motivation: I'm trying to understand  the equation: $\partial_t n + \text{div} (nu)=0, x \in \mathbb T^3, t>0$ (Navier-stack equation on 3 dimensional torus).

Answer (score 2):

In Euclidian coordinates, we have that
$$\operatorname{div}(nu)=\partial_i (nu_i)=(\partial_i n)u_i+n \partial_iu_i=\operatorname{grad}(n)\cdot u+ n \operatorname{div}(u)$$

Comment: This solution uses Einstein's notation for the sums of partial derivatives.

Comment: @gdepaul Of course. I didn't note it in the answer, because it's a physics-ish topic.